# Экранирование символов регулярного выражения в многобайтовых строках на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

У меня есть регулярное выражение которое содержит внешние данные, если из внешних данных поступит строка содержащая служебные символы регулярного выражения то это покоцает весь паттерн, пытался найти встроенную функцию для экранирования символов в многобайтовых строках- не нашел.
Как экранировать символы регулярного выражения?
Пример:

```
function f(string $data)
{
    //Здесь сначала нужно экранировать символы в строке, но как это сделать?
    $data = screening($data);
    //Затем передать в паттерн регулярного выражения
    string $pattern = "^\{$data}+|{$data}+$";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Специально для таких целей придумали функцию [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, вроде никакие спецсимволы не забыл.

```
$data=preg_replace('/([[\]\\.?*(){}+^$|\/])/','\\\\$1',$data);
```

И в регулярке когда пишите `{$data}+` пишите лучше в скобках `({$data})+`, а то `+` будет распространятся только на последний символ строки.